# Using indexes in nested Handlebar's loops

Tags: handlebars.js

I am trying to create the following table.

[image]

I have passed `o` to handlebars (PS.  I could restructure this object.  Should I?).

```
var o={
years:[1800,1900,2012],
countries:["Africa","America","Asia","Europe","Oceania"],
data:[
  [107,133,1052],
  [null,156,954],
  [635,null,4250],
  [203,408,740],
  [2,6,38]
  ]
};
```

According to http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html, I can access the index via `{{@index}}`.  But since I have two loops, how do I access both of them so I can get the correct data?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th></th> 
            {{#each years}} {{!-- is "#each years" and "#years" the same thing??? --}} 
            <th>{{this}}</th> 
            {{/each}} 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        {{#each countries}} 
        <tr> 
        <td>{{this}}</td> 
        {{#each data}} 
        <tr> 
            <td>{{this}}????</td> 
        </tr> 
        {{/each}} 
        </tr> 
        {{/each}} 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `{{#each years}}` *will* have the same result as `{{#years}}`. The latter form is from [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) and is what the library refers to as a [Section](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Sections). The Handlebars docs explain the [differences between Handlebars block expressions and Mustache Sections](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/#differences-between-handlebarsjs-and-mustache).

The reason you cannot use `{{#each data}}` from within your `{{#each countries}}` loop is because the data context within the countries loop is the current country iteration. You must reach up to the parent scope in order to have access to the `data` object. This is done with [Handlebars paths](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths) and would be written as `{{../data}}`.

However, in our scenario we wish to grab a particular element of `data`, the index of which matches the index of our current country iteration. For this, we can use the [lookup helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup). The result would be the following:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th></th> 
            {{#each years}}
                <th>{{this}}</th> 
            {{/each}} 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        {{#each countries}} 
            <tr> 
                <td>{{this}}</td> 
                {{#each (lookup ../data @index)}} 
                    <tr> 
                        <td>{{this}}</td> 
                    </tr> 
                {{/each}} 
            </tr> 
        {{/each}} 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```